# Jquery color box is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, jquery-minicolors

Requirement  :I  need  open  pop up using  jquery colorbox plugin

These  are  sequence  of  plugins  which  i am using using :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/newUI/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/newUI/jQuery/plugins/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/newUI/jQuery/plugins/colorbox/colorbox.css" />
```

Below  javascript function :

```
function XXXXXXXXX() {   
    jQuery.colorbox(
        {
            overlayClose:true,
            href:"/newUI/new.jsp",
            onClosed:removeColor,
            innerHeight:280 , 
            scrolling:false
        }
    );
}
```

Error  message :  I am  getting  jquery colorbox is  not a function , actually few pages its  working  fine  and  few pages its not  working need some  assistance on  this issue.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws3Pk.png)

Expected :Onclick of hyper link  pop up message  should open using jquery  colorbox
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzzwI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your code is executed after the DOM is fully loaded. You can do this by wrapping your code in a `document.ready` block if you're using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function someFunction() {
        jQuery.colorbox(
            {
                overlayClose:true,
                href:"/newUI/new.jsp",
                onClosed:removeColor,
                innerHeight:280, 
                scrolling:false
            }
        );
    }
});
```